# Can I label each of the Windows10 Ubuntu terminals?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I opened multiple Win10 Ubuntu terminals, each runs very similar programs. To minimise the confusion, can I label each terminal on its title? Of course, I can use `pwd` to know the different working directories but it takes time to check every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest might be to change the font color in one (or both) terminal instances.

- Open terminal.
- From the *Edit* menu, select *Preferences*.
- Change the font color, size, etc. so as to distinguish that instance.

Comment: I will quickly forget which color corresponds which terminal